# Extracting vanc data/frame hexdump from a video file

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing, mediainfo

Is it possible to extract line 23 data, which allows signaling of the source (coded image) aspect ratio and the Active Format Descriptor, using ffmpeg?

I believe this might be possible in mediainfo but it doesnt have a binary representation option, just strings.

Answer (score 0):

> I believe this might be possible in mediainfo

Are you speaking about "line 23" [burned in the encoded frame i.e. in the top of the visible content](https://nootropicdesign.com/projectlab/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/closedCaption2-sm.jpg), in [VBI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_blanking_interval) uncompressed side data (SD content), or in [VANC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancillary_data) uncompressed side data (HD content)?

Beside A/53 DTG1, A/53 GA94, MediaInfo supports aspect ratio and the Active Format Description in VANC (SMPTE ST 2016).

> but it doesnt have a binary representation option, just strings.

If you need to have the exact bytes of VANC or VBI, it is possible to adapt a bit (some development) [MediaInfo](https://mediaarea.net/MediaInfo) for that (burned line 23 requires frame decoding so out of the scope of MediaInfo, but also doable, with higher cost), [contact us](https://mediaarea.net/Contact) if you don't find free solution for what you are looking for.

Jérôme,
    Developer of [MediaInfo](https://mediaarea.net/MediaInfo)